# Stack Exchange - Deleted Answer Manager

Tags: script, chrome-extensions, 10k-tools

**Description**

This script hides the content of deleted answers (which are visible to 10k+ Stack Exchange users), injects a show content / hide content toggle in the answer's menu, and injects a visibility toggle for all hidden questions into the page.

[image: Functionality screenshot]

**Notes**

Based on a few comments below, *as of June 2017 I have updated and republished the Chrome extension.*

If you like/use the extension, please rate it in the Chrome store. Additionally, before UserScripts.org shut down, the script saw a lot of activity there. If a similar site has taken its place in popularity, please let me know in the comments below so that I can post it there as well.

**Installation**

This script is [now available as a Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-exchange-deleted-an/hmcfjaackkkkohogfoofjbfohjgpmibn).

**Update Information**

**1.6**

- Script now aborts if there are no deleted answers.
- Relevant answer text now only shows if there are relevant answers (showed 0 before).
- After settings change, users is prompted to reload page.

**1.5** - Republished Chrome extension

**1.4** - Deleted answer manager now works on all StackExchange sites.

**1.3** - Fixed HTML injection, updated to latest jquery.

**1.0** - Added link for Google Chrome extension.

**1.0** - Modify the page only if deleted answer(s) exist.

**0.9** - Fixed bug in show/hide content logic.

**0.8** - Added ability to save preferences using `localStorage`.

**0.7** - Initial post on Stack Apps.

Comment: How do I enable this on Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: @ChrisF, scratch the previous comment. This is now available for all StackExchange sites. Because of my rep limitations, I can only test is on StackOverflow. If you (or anyone) can test it on other StackExchange sites, I'd appreciate the feedback!

Comment: I'll try to remember to give a try when I get home.

Comment: I've been using the 1.0 user script version with Greasemonkey/Firefox for more than a year now on Arqade and it works fine. The user script download link is currently missing. Can it be hosted on another site?

Comment: @galacticninja, check out http://userscripts-mirror.org/. UserScripts went down a long time ago and is not coming back. I'm currently only hosting this as a Chrome extension.

Comment: It currently states "Item not found. This item may have been removed by its author." when I try to access the Chrome webstore page.

Comment: @galacticninja you can use a mirror http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/133048

Comment: @Nikita, I had less than 20 users who actually used this script. I'm happy to republish and continue supporting if there is continued/more interest.

Comment: @Nikita I'm aware of the mirror site. However, the Chrome extension (when it was still in the Chrome webstore) was more recently updated than the script. James Hill: Count me in as one of the interested users.

Comment: @galacticninja, roger that. I'll dig up the source files, update, and republish. Based on the link that Nikita posted from UserScripts, it looked like the plugin got more use than I realized. The Chrome store told a different tale. Any suggestions on where else I should post it now that UserScripts is dead?

Comment: OK, @galacticninja, the extension is up. Can you test it out for me? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hmcfjaackkkkohogfoofjbfohjgpmibn/publish-accepted?hl=en-US&gl=US

Comment: @JamesHill I tried it on a few questions in gaming.stackexchange.com and it seems to work fine. Thanks for that. As for the user script site, I've looked at my user scripts and most of them are hosted at GitHub, greasyfork.org and openuserjs.org.

Comment: When the entire question is deleted, it says "1 Deleted Answer". I didn't find this too confusing before, but with the change to the location of "Related questions" today, it's confusing because this is above that message.

Comment: Hi, @Barmar. Thanks for your feedback. I'll be honest, I haven't updated that extension in 6 years. It currently has just 5 active users. I'm going to go ahead and pull it from the store.

Comment: Looks like they've reverted that format change so this is now moot.